# Windows 7 Online Desktop Background Changer

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop-customization

I am looking for a software which will change my desktop background image every 30 minutes - 1 hour from some random gallery online, I do not care much.

I am looking for high - res pictures ( 2000 something to 1044 monitor.. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No on premise support for this , you will have grab a third party tool

i would recommend   [John's Background Switcher](http://johnsadventures.com/software/backgroundswitcher/)

It supports features like  auto exit, time intervals, selecting images from the folders in PC and from other online resources picasa, facebook galleries, flickr, Yahoo ,etc 
[image]

NOTE : the tool does not works for all the online photos, galleries

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. But I do not have many images in my harddrive.

Comment: i edited the answer, check now if this tool helps

Comment: Appearntly searching google images do not work after a while. I contacted the developer, said it was depracted by google. Shame..

Answer (score 1):

try [this](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/Landscape-Online-Wallpaper-Changer.shtml), which is an online wall paper changing software. any way for these kind of needs, you will be having a limited number of channel for getting wallpaper.